# SetInterval firing at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

On the function on this code, `whatareyousingingpatrick(),`, whenever the function is called a new element and setinterval should be called, however it doesn't seem like a new one is created with a new `original` variable, it just seems like the same one gets fired over and over. :)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<body onclick="whatareyousingingpatrick();" onkeypress="pretend();">
<span id="money">25</span>$ - <span id="lives">100</span>/100 lives - Level: <span id="level">1</span>
<br><br>
<span style="background-color:#c3c3c3;width:1000px;height:175px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;display:block;" id="track"></span>
<br>
<span id="divthing" style="position:relative;display:block;"></span>


<script>
    money = 25;
    lives = 100;
    mycars = {};

    function doofus() {
if($("div:first").offset().left > 1000){
        $("div:first").remove();
        lives = lives-1;
        document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = lives;
}
}

    function dodat() {
        var btn = document.createElement("div");
        btn.style.width = "25px";
        btn.style.height = "25px";
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        btn.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
        btn.style.position = "absolute";
        btn.style.left = "0px";
        btn.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 1s";
        var numba = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
        btn.class = "haha";
        btn.id = numba;
        mycars[numba] = -50;

        var move = function () {
            mycars[numba] = mycars[numba] + 1.5;
            document.getElementById(numba).style.left = mycars[numba] + "px";
            if(mycars[numba] > 100 && mycars[numba] < 150){
            document.getElementById(numba).style.top = mycars[numba]/0.5-200 + "px";
            }
        };

        setInterval(move, 10);

        document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
    }

    setInterval(dodat, 2000);
    setInterval(doofus, 200);

    function dis1() {
        $("shooter").css("background-color", "red");
        setTimeout('$("shooter").css("background-color", "blue");', '1000');
    compareEl = $("#shoot1");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls = $('div'),
            compareTop = compareEl.offset().top,
            compareLeft = compareEl.offset().left,
            winningScore = Infinity,
            score, winner, curEl;

        otherEls.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl = $(this);
            score = Math.abs(curEl.offset().left - compareLeft);
            if (score < winningScore) {
                winningScore = score;
                winner = this;
            }
        });
        document.getElementById(winner.id).style.opacity="0";

        money = money+1;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=""+money+"";
}

    function dis2() {
   compareEl2 = $("#shoot2");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls2 = $('div'),
            compareTop2 = compareEl2.offset().top,
            compareLeft2 = compareEl2.offset().left,
            winningScore2 = Infinity,
            score2, winner2, curEl2;

        otherEls2.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl2 = $(this);
            score2 = Math.abs(curEl2.offset().left - compareLeft2);
            if (score2 < winningScore2) {
                winningScore2 = score;
                winner2 = this;
            }
        });

        document.getElementById(winner2.id).style.opacity="0";
}


    function dis3() {
   compareEl3 = $("#shoot3");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls3 = $('div'),
            compareTop3 = compareEl3.offset().top,
            compareLeft3 = compareEl3.offset().left,
            winningScore3 = Infinity,
            score3, winner3, curEl3;

        otherEls3.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl3 = $(this);
            score3 = Math.abs(curEl3.offset().left - compareLeft3);
            if (score3 < winningScore3) {
                winningScore3 = score;
                winner3 = this;
            }
        });

        document.getElementById(winner3.id).style.opacity="0";
}


function dis4(){
   compareEl4 = $("#shoot4");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls4 = $('div'),
            compareTop4 = compareEl4.offset().top,
            compareLeft4 = compareEl4.offset().left,
            winningScore4 = Infinity,
            score4, winner4, curEl4;

        otherEls4.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl4 = $(this);
            score4 = Math.abs(curEl4.offset().left - compareLeft4);
            if (score4 < winningScore4) {
                winningScore4 = score;
                winner4 = this;
            }
        });

        document.getElementById(winner4.id).style.opacity="0";
}

original = 0;
function whatareyousingingpatrick(){
if(money >= 1){
money = money+10000000;
original = original+1;
    setInterval("dis"+original+"();alert("+original+");", original+500);
        var btn = document.createElement("shooter");
        btn.style.display = "block";
        btn.id = "shoot"+original+"";
        btn.style.height = "25px";
        btn.style.width = "25px";
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        btn.innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/1317280976_1370202845.png' style='height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:100%;opacity:0.7;'>";
        btn.style.borderRadius= "100%";
        btn.style.boxShadow= "0px 0px 200px 75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
        btn.style.position = "absolute";
        btn.style.left = event.pageX-20;
        btn.style.top = event.pageY-250;
        document.getElementById("divthing").appendChild(btn);
}
else{
alert("Sorry, this dude costs over 25 bucks.");
}
}

function pretend(){
if(money >= 60){
money = money-60;
   if (event.keyCode == 49) {
   alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your first missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
   setInterval("dis1();", "1000");
   }
   if (event.keyCode == 50) {
   alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your second missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
   setInterval("dis2();", "1000");
   }
   if (event.keyCode == 51) {
   alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your third missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
   setInterval("dis3();", "1000");
   }
   if (event.keyCode == 52) {
   alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your fourth missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
   setInterval("dis4();", "1000");
   }
}
else
{
alert("Sorry, the cost of the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for this missile is 60$");
}
}
</script>

<script>
setTimeout('document.getElementById("level").innerHTML="2";setInterval(dodat, 8000);', '40000');
</script>
<br><br>
```

Comment: You should work on reducing the amount of code in your question to a bare minimum example.

Comment: The first argument of setInterval should be a function not a string.

Comment: example? @MarshallHouse

Answer (score 2):

i didn't read all of your code. But this fixes at least a portion of your problem:

```
setInterval("dis"+original+"();alert("+original+");", original+500);
```

Should be:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var func = 'dis' + original;
    func();

    alert(original); //for some reason
}, original+500);
```

Comment: setInterval sucks btw.

Comment: The function you provide should re-call itself using setTimeout. it's less buggy than setInterval.

Comment: Wait- I keep getting a "ncaught TypeError: string is not a function" error when I use your code. any idea why?

Comment: the concatenated "dis" + original must not be mapping to a defined function. Another tip; pass your parameters through the functions, instead of relying on their global value.