# I have a button that calls a javascript function using an event handler. For some reason, the event handler is being called automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am new to javascript and I have called a function using a button in HTML.
I have also added onclick action. but still, it is getting triggering automatically all the time.

```
<input class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-800 text-white font-light py-1 px-2 rounded-full" onclick="fun_on()" type="button"value="ON"></input>
                  
                   <script>
                    setInterval(fun_on<?php echo $devicename;?>,500);
                    function fun_on<?php echo $devicename;?>(){
                      var device_name='<?php echo $devicename;?>';
                      var on = 1;
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data: { on:on },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                          $('#control_data<?php echo $devicename;?>').html(data);
                        }
                      });
                    }
                  </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SetInterval firing at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591161/setinterval-firing-at-the-same-time)

Comment: you need to use quotes for the function name when it's an argument of `setInterval`. so it'd be `setInterval('fun_on<?php echo $devicename;?>'`

Comment: *for **some reason** it is getting triggering automatically all the time* - because it's run by `setInterval`?

Comment: `setInterval(`  did you mean `setTimeout(`??

Comment: Also, your onclick is `onclick="fun_on()"`, but your function name is `function fun_on<?php echo $devicename;?>(){` - assuming the php actually does *something* here, then the function won't be `fun_on()` so your onclick would also not work.

Comment: My mistake, I thought `$devicename` also contained '()' as string in `php` but reading the code it's not the case.

Comment: thank you, freedomn-m as you said that was triggering only because the PHP code something there.

Comment: It's in `setInterval` so it obviously triggers automatically, If you want your function to trigger on click remove it from there.